# Automapper map child object based on parent value

Tags: c#, automapper

If the header object has a prop set to 1 then it should map field type1 in the child to type in the destination. Otherwise it should use type2.

Bonus points if I can use `IValueResolver` to use type1 or type1extended if extended is filled.

Here is my minimum viable product/demo

```
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleAppAutoMapper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new SourceParent() {
                Header = new SourceHeader() { Currency = 30, FileName = "testfile.txt", Type = 1 },
                Rows = new List<SourceRow>() {
                    new SourceRow() { ID = 1, Amount1 = 100, Amount2 = 200 },
                    new SourceRow() { ID = 2, Amount1 = 101, Amount2 = 201 },
                    new SourceRow() { ID = 3, Amount1 = 102, Amount2 = 202 }
                } };

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<SourceParent, DestinationParent>();
                cfg.CreateMap<SourceRow, DestinationRow>()
                    .ForMember(x => x.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Type1));
            });

            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            var dest = mapper.Map<DestinationParent>(source);

            Console.WriteLine(dest.Rows[0].Type == 100); // should be true if SourceHeader.Type = 1 and should be 200 (SourceRow.Type2) if SourceHeader.Type = 2
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    // source

    public class SourceParent
    {
        public SourceHeader Header { get; set; }
        public List<SourceRow> Rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceHeader
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceRow
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Amount1 { get; set; }
        public int Amount2 { get; set; }
    }

    //destination

    public class DestinationParent
    {
        public DestinationHeader Header { get; set; }
        public List<DestinationRow> Rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class DestinationHeader
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }

    public class DestinationRow
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public int Amount{ get; set; }  // if type=1 then source is amount1 otherwise amount2
    }
}
```

**edit**
I tried to solve it by having an `Aftermap` on the sourceparent mapping which took the value from the header and put it in a prop from the destinationrow (it is the `Type` value) and wanted another aftermap on the row to see if I needed prop A or B (type1 or type2) but that aftermap still does not know (it's null) what type it is because it happens before the aftermap of the parent it seems.

```
public class MapRowType : IMappingAction<SourceParent, DestinationParent>
{
    public void Process(SourceParentsource, DestinationParent destination)
    {
        foreach (var row in destination.Rows)
        {
            row.Type = source.Header.Type; // so now I have type in the row, but still do not know if I should use Amount1 or Amount2 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your source entity schema doesn't have any navigation from `SourceRow` to `SourceParent` so as far as static mapping rules go - this is probably impossible.

Comment: So what would you suggest to do after I have added a property to the SourceRow with the value of the SourceParent in it?

Comment: Yes and likewise `SourceHeader` property to `SourceParent`, your conditional mapping requirement then becomes trivial. Right now, in your object to object mapping strategy declaration (Automapper profile config), as far as each `SourceRow` object is concerned, it is on its own and doesn't belong to `SourceParent`. You can ofcourse, achieve your desired behaviour without adding extra properties, just not via Automapper then.

Comment: I used an aftermap to set the type to the rows and used an aftermap on the row mapping to try and pick either amount1 or 2 based on type value. But in that aftermap the type is still null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the resolution context. Declare the mapping:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceRow, DestinationRow>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Type, 
                       opt => opt.ResolveUsing((src, dest1, destMember, resContext) => resContext.Items["Type"] as int? == 1? src.Type2: src.Type1));
```

After pass the value:

```
var dest = mapper.Map<DestinationParent>(source, opts=> { opts.Items["Type"] = source.Header.Type;});
```

Comment: But the `ResolutionContext` only contains the contextual information for the current resolution operation. The conditional resolution logic he is looking for is based on the object which owns the collection that the object being resolved belongs to.

Comment: You can set the value of ResolutionContext by doing the mapping as I have put it in the example and it works. 
In order not to use ResolutionContext it is possible to define a more complex mapping

Comment: Yeah, I can see now what you are proposing here. I guess you at least have to forfeit `mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DestinationParent>>` then, but good suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: Is there no easy/easier way to set the type value for all destination child/rows? I tried to use two Aftermaps. One on the parent and one on the row. The parent one works, but the row one is still `null` at the moment it is processed.

Comment: Visual Studio says that there is no `ResolveUsing` for the IMemberConfigurationExpression.

Comment: @JPHellemons If you use this way, the resolutionContext in ResolveUsing, all daughter rows have the same behavior. it is not necessary to use the AfterMap method.

Comment: @JPHellemons Can be by the Automapper version. I have used version 6.2.2. https://dotnetfiddle.net/VgtfZM

Comment: I used the latest Nuget 8.0.0

Comment: @JPHellemons Try with this mapping:
cfg.CreateMap<SourceRow, DestinationRow>()
     .AfterMap((src, dest, resContext) => 
     {
      dest.Type = resContext.Items["Type"] as int? == 2? src.Type2: src.Type1;
     });

Comment: @asd Your example doesn't _set_ the resolution context. It adds a value to the Items dictionary _in_ the resolution context. But other than the wording, nice suggestion. In later versions, `ResolveUsing()` was consolidated into `MapFrom()`, which now has an overload that gives access to the resolution context.